# Can I integrate grapejs website builder into my own website

Tags: integration, grapesjs

Does anyone know if I can integrate GrapeJS into my own website so clients could build their own websites using it? IF anyone has done this, how easy is it and are there downsides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

However it is not straightforward.

If you want to build a Drag Drop Editor like GrapeJS Demo, here is the Source Code - https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-preset-webpage

You can see an implementation at https://codegres.org/dragdrop

Answer (score 5):

This question is pretty open ended, but I'll take a shot at it.

The short answer is yes, you can use Grapesjs to allow clients to make their own sites; however, the details matter.

Grapesjs by default doesn't know anything about your stack, website structure, metadata, etc. You will need to either supply plugins or implement those features yourself. I've worked on a project for a company that used Grapesjs to implement single page apps and I'll include just some of the tweaks we had to manage.

- Hiding certain layers that only confuse average users.
- Hiding pretty much all of the styling, and using traits to allow people to pick from some predefined styles.
- Take the html, css on store and generate the final html page, and store it in our static serving folder on the server.
- Implement a wrapping "App" component that has traits for the different metadata we want users to control (open graph metadata, title, etc)

and those are just the big things, I'm sure I am forgetting several small ones.

For your application, you'll also need to implement a custom trait for links / buttons that allows you to link from one "page" to another. As well as, a way to allow a user to pick which page to work on.

The long answer is Yes, but Grapesjs is only the starting point.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had found this and it seemed like a template library for what I am looking for...... I think? https://grapesjs.com/docs/getting-started.html#import-the-library